# Invalid depfile: Flutter

Tags: flutter, import

I am following a tutorial from a udemy course and recently I built a new pc so the hard drive that stored my code is secondary right now. When I compile the code, it gives me the following error. To explain it better, I am posting a picture of one warning in my code but I am pretty sure it is an error flutter is making as it usually does with imports. [Error in Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZqTx.png)
    I have tried running a test app by making a default app from cmd and that works fine. So obviously, flutter doctor shows no error. the error is repetitive and long so I am pasting some of it below.

The error-

```
Invalid depfile: D:\WorkSpace\Code\Flutter\Image App\image_app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\8f0d0eee9ef614ed024ca7691a333af8\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: D:\WorkSpace\Code\Flutter\Image App\image_app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\8f0d0eee9ef614ed024ca7691a333af8\kernel_snapshot.d

Compiler message:
Error: Could not resolve the package 'http' in 'package:http/http.dart'.
lib/src/app.dart:5:8: Error: Expected ';' after this.
import 'widgets/image_list.dart;'
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/src/app.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'package:http/http.dart'
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get; //Only need get so we only care about one Get fuction
       ^
lib/src/app.dart:5:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/src/widgets/image_list.dart;': The system cannot find the file specified.

import 'widgets/image_list.dart;'
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart:9:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/dluck/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.0.8/lib/vector_math_64.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' show Vector3;
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/widgets.dart:15:1: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/dluck/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.0.8/lib/vector_math_64.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

export 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' show Matrix4;
^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/rendering.dart:31:1: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/dluck/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.0.8/lib/vector_math_64.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

export 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' show Matrix4;
^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/dluck/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.0.8/lib/vector_math_64.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart';
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/transitions.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/dluck/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.0.8/lib/vector_math_64.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' show Matrix4;
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:27:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/dluck/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.0.8/lib/vector_math_64.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart';
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/foundation.dart:12:1: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/dluck/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.1.8/lib/meta.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart:90:4: Error: Getter not found: 'mustCallSuper'.
  @mustCallSuper
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart:90:4: Error: This can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
  @mustCallSuper
   ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart:104:4: Error: Getter not found: 'mustCallSuper'.
  @mustCallSuper
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart:104:4: Error: This can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
  @mustCallSuper
   ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart:118:4: Error: Getter not found: 'protected'.
  @protected
   ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart:118:4: Error: This can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
  @protected
   ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart:119:4: Error: Getter not found: 'mustCallSuper'.
  @mustCallSuper
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart:119:4: Error: This can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
  @mustCallSuper
   ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart:139:4: Error: Getter not found: 'protected'.
  @protected
   ^^^^^^^^^

C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:3970:4: Error: This can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
  @required TextDirection thisTextDirection,
   ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:3971:4: Error: Getter not found: 'required'.
  @required TextDirection otherTextDirection,
   ^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:3971:4: Error: This can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
  @required TextDirection otherTextDirection,
   ^
U
nhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:
package%3Ahttp%2Fhttp.dart; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFi
leSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileU
ri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:604:37)
#
2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front
_end.dart:799:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#
3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:fron
tend_server/frontend_server.dart:472:15)
<asynchronous 
suspension>
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.comp
ile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dar
t:38:22)
#5      starter (package:flutter_fronte
nd_server/server.dart:149:27)
#6      main (f
ile:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/fl
utter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:8:30)
#7    
  _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isol
ate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:32)
#8      _RawRec
eivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch
/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Did you try the command "flutter pub get" ? Because it looks like one of your packages is not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so I found out since I changed the PC, I needed to change permissions of a file. 
Follow here
https://github.com/simolus3/moor/issues/224

Answer (score 57):

Sometimes it happens to me too. I either deleted the converted code or converted it command
For example here I entered:

```
import 'dart:html';
```

, And my error was fixed after deleting it or turning it into a comment

```
// import 'dart:html';
```

Comment: works like charm, why the html make this error?

Comment: In my case, I need to remove `import 'dart:js';`

Comment: Thats horrible, I checked my code and accidently I also imported dart:html, after deleting unnecessary import its solved. thank you

Comment: Hmm, how do I identify which import is affected? I neither have any "dart:html" nor "dart:js" imports.

Answer (score 46):

I got the same error and I am following a udemy course as well.
I tried `flutter pub get` and it worked.

Answer (score 19):

i also faced the same problem and i sort out by running "flutter clean" command.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21053

Answer (score 11):

you need clean the project
run "flutter Clean" in the project and later run the project normal

Answer (score 10):

```
Invalid depfile: D:\...\f5\.dart_tool\flutter_build\8e234dd4da26339b660f6097cc2a271a\kernel_snapshot.d
```

Delete `kernel_snapshot.d` and `kernel_snapshot.stamp` files at this location:

```
your flutter project\.dart_tool\flutter_build\8e234dd4da26339b660f6097cc2a271a
```

Comment: This worked for me but I still want to know the reason behind this.

Answer (score 9):

I face similar problem I solved it by deleting **import 'dart:html';** from top of the dart file. i.e remove
`import 'dart:html';`

Answer (score 6):

well, you can do two steps to fix this issue

```
1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
```

after running these commands it should fix your issue

Answer (score 6):

I have the same bug and I deactivated vs code. When I reactivated it, I just typed

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get 

flutter run
```

And everything started to work.

Answer (score 4):

Like many of you have suggested, I tried out almost all the things mentioned here and several other StackOverflow posts. But nothing worked for me.

The build error I got:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           17.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Invalid depfile: /Users/MY_APP_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME/app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9a159911376355ed7b90130da2eaf0aa/kernel_snapshot.d
    Invalid depfile: /Users/MY_APP_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME/app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9a159911376355ed7b90130da2eaf0aa/kernel_snapshot.d
    Invalid depfile: /Users/MY_APP_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME/app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9a159911376355ed7b90130da2eaf0aa/kernel_snapshot.d
    Invalid depfile: /Users/MY_APP_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME/app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9a159911376355ed7b90130da2eaf0aa/kernel_snapshot.d
    Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'shared_preferences' in 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart'.
    ../lib/ui/home/home_screen.dart:29:8: Error: Not found: 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart'
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
           ^
    ../lib/ui/home/home_screen.dart:871:37: Error: The getter 'SharedPreferences' isn't defined for the class '_HomeScreenState'.
     - '_HomeScreenState' is from 'package:PACKAGE_NAME/ui/home/home_screen.dart' ('../lib/ui/home/home_screen.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'SharedPreferences'.
        final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../lib/ui/home/home_screen.dart:893:37: Error: The getter 'SharedPreferences' isn't defined for the class '_HomeScreenState'.
     - '_HomeScreenState' is from 'package:PACKAGE_NAME/ui/home/home_screen.dart' ('../lib/ui/home/home_screen.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'SharedPreferences'.
        final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Unhandled exception:
    FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:package%3Ashared_preferences%2Fshared_preferences.dart; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
    #0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
    #1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:614:37)
    #2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:754:21)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:570:9)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #4      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:85:12)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:13:24)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    Failed to package /Users/MY_APP_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME/app.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/MY_APP_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/MY_APP_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

One of the solutions that looked promising was deleting two files; `kernel_snapshot.d` and `kernel_snapshot.stamp` however that also didn't work for me. But I went to the path where these two files were residing. You can have a look into the folders and files structure in the following screenshot:

[image: The folders and files I deleted]

So what I did is actually delete those files that have been selected in the following screenshot and then try running the app as usual on the simulator. And it worked.

Answer (score 4):

While you are writing the code, this library is import by itself. ( import 'dart:html';)This causes some problems. You can delete it from the code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: check again please and till me

Comment: Thanks. In my case, it is this file that was imported which was causing the error: import 'dart:js_interop';
I removed it and everything was fine.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, try to delete unused imports in your project!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this.
At first you have to check if you added the related dependencies on the pubspec.yaml file
like below:

web_socket case ==>

( on pubspec.yaml )

dependencies:
**web_socket_channel: ^1.1.0**
flutter:
sdk:flutter

Answer (score 1):

If you're on VS code "try **flutter clean** then **flutter run**" on terminal

Answer (score 1):

Fixing problems in "Dart Analysis" tab solved the problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error and later on came to find out that I had imported web-only dependency in my pubspec file.

In my case.

```
firebase: ^5.0.0
```

This is only for web.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out the issue was caused by import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart'; in
my project to Fix it delete that import

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same problem and solution:

```
flutter clean .
```

- 

```
flutter create .
```

This is a solution that I always try before almost any problem, then if it is not solved I see it in ..

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look if you have added such an import?

```
    import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';
```

If so, this is for the web. If you are writing a mobile application, then it is better to use such an import :

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

This could be a potential error.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any import which is related to **browser** or **http** and if your target platform is mobile then you might not need browser import and you can remove it.

In my case, I have **removed** this.

```
import 'package:dart_web3/browser.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone has a solution to delete kernel_snapshot.d and kernel_snapshot.stamp

Well,
I did but error not gone. What i did else is to check other errors and other errors was coming from Stripe Package. So i commented like this #flutter_stripe ^2.1.1 on pubspec.yaml and also, do Pub get: Note : Any error you see after commented or removed sdk package on pubs make sure you remove those errors else, after that, clean  build folder on xcode and run pod install. The error gone. For you and anyone else, check other errors below the red or yellow highlight on Xcode. You may see other error which may not shown on Buldtime Nav. also make sure you use the latest Xcode Version.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. The way around it is to look on the home page or the main page, comment out or delete the 'import dart.html' and save, and then run flutter run. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Before running 'flutter pub get'

Go to the dependencies folder e.g. or whichever your app is pointing to ...

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev
```

Look for the dependency that is misbehaving and just delete it.

Then run 'flutter pub get' to re-download it

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score -1):

I add this code it will run

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show BuildContext, Colors, Column, Expanded, Key, MainAxisAlignment, MaterialApp, Row, Scaffold, Size, SizedBox, StatelessWidget, Text, TextButton, Widget, runApp;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).