# Invalid depfile ...kernel_snapshot.d

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I was following a simple tutorial on Youtube it was about routes and maps in flutter. I created simple routes and tried the navigator.pushNamed function. The code itself doesn't have any error, however when I try running it on my AVD, it shows a long error which I am not quite sure what it's about.

'''

```
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\suyas\AndroidStudioProjects\world_time\.dart_tool\flutter_build\633c5927f281cdb2910d4c731b292e86\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\suyas\AndroidStudioProjects\world_time\.dart_tool\flutter_build\633c5927f281cdb2910d4c731b292e86\kernel_snapshot.d
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatabl
e-uri:
dart%3Ajs; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:599:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:738:21)
<asynchronous suspensio
n>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:558:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (pa
ckage:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:180:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (fil
e:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.da
rt:13:24)
<asynchronous suspension>



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

'''

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to rebuild the references used in the Flutter project? Rebuilding the references used in the project usually solves the issue as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872753/invalid-depfile-flutter).

Answer (score 4):

Remove import dart:html then it will work