# Flutter project doesn't run and show some strange error?

Tags: flutter, dependencies

Hello I am beginner in the flutter I am build a project which show the some errors which is below

```
Launching lib\main.dart on M2101K6P in debug mode...
Invalid depfile: D:\Flutter\New\myshop\.dart_tool\flutter_build\47f264e5c74e90bdb7e06ba89ca44716\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: D:\Flutter\New\myshop\.dart_tool\flutter_build\47f264e5c74e90bdb7e06ba89ca44716\kernel_snapshot.d
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:654:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:794:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:629:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:99:12)

<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13:14)
<asynchronous suspension>

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

And there are my dependencies from the pubsback.yml file

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.5
  intl: ^0.18.0
  http: ^0.13.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
```

The error is because of any dependencies version or any other problem form the code, so What the error message tell what's wrong please explain this thing?

This is my main.dart code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myshop/screens/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './screens/products_overview_screen.dart';
import './screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import './screens/cart_screen.dart';
import './screens/order_screen.dart';
import './screens/user_products_screen.dart';
import './screens/edit_product_screen.dart';
import '../screens/authentication_screen.dart';

import './providers/products.dart';
import './providers/cart.dart';
import './providers/order.dart';
import './providers/auth.dart';
import './providers/auth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // here new instance of Products is creating so here we have to use the builder methode insted of .value
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => Auth()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
            create: (_) => Products('', '', []),
            update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
                  auth.token,
                  auth.userId,
                  previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
                )),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Cart(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Order>(
          create: (ctx) => Order('', '', []),
          update: (ctx, auth, order) => Order(
            auth.token!,
            auth.userId!,
            order == null ? [] : order.orders,
          ),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Auth>(builder: (ctx, authData, _) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyShop',
          theme: ThemeData(
            fontFamily: 'Lato',
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch()
                .copyWith(primary: Colors.purple, secondary: Colors.deepOrange),
          ),
          home: authData.isAuth
              ? ProductOverviewScreen()
              : FutureBuilder(
                  builder: (ctx, authSnapShot) =>
                      authSnapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                          ? SplashScreen()
                          : AuthenticationScreen()),
          routes: {
            ProductOverviewScreen.routeName: (context) =>
                ProductOverviewScreen(),
            AuthenticationScreen.routeName: (context) => AuthenticationScreen(),
            ProductDetailScreen.routeName: (context) => ProductDetailScreen(),
            CartScreen.routeName: (context) => CartScreen(),
            OrderScreen.routeName: (context) => OrderScreen(),
            UserProductsScreen.routeName: (context) => UserProductsScreen(),
            EditProductScreen.namedRoute: (context) => EditProductScreen(),
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi .Can you show the code which you are running

Comment: I have lots of pages and other stuffs that I couldn't show you here, but I only share main.dart code

Comment: I attach the main.dart code in question

Comment: Maybe this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872753/invalid-depfile-flutter

Comment: Check if you also have the import 'dart:html' somewhere on one of your pages ; It sometimes gets generated automatically and cause issues